# How do I display a continuous chain of image slides using SlideJS?

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am using SlidesJS (http://slidesjs.com/) as a JavaScript image slider on my site. How can I go about altering either the CSS or JavaScript to allow for images to be displayed on both the left and right side of each other? As you can see in the default SlidesJS image slider, only one image is displayed at a time; however, I would like for multiple slides (one on the left and right side of the main center image) to be displayed at once similar to how this site does it:http://www.reedandbarton.com/ and this site: http://www.freundevonfreunden.com/

If SlidesJS is not possible to alter to achieve such functionality, and recommendations for a JavaScript slider that can?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you want something like this. I am sure it will help you:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/19982181/easyslider1.7.zip

Comment: Thank you, this is nice. Quick question - do you know how I would go about keeping a slide centered when the page loads and even when the user resizes the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the page example you gave the site is using [easyslider](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding) look at the options on that page and you should be able to achieve what you want.

The example page options can be seen [here](http://www.freundevonfreunden.com/wp-content/themes/fvonf/js/script.js)

Answer (score 0):

Definitely possible.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yFcch/

Revise the codes as you wish.

Comment: thanks for this...how would i go about making the slides "chained" so they are all connected and move in a continuous flow?

Comment: See the codes inside the fiddle, inside the class `slides_container`. Put all your images to be chained inside it. The example I've shown you there is a continuous flow, but I used the same dummy image, so replace the images to see the actual effect.